Newbie: System policy prevents Wi-Fi Scans
Please bear with me as my experience on Linux is very limited.
I have installed a LinuxCNC workstation which is based on Debian 12. I have installed TightVNC for remote control.
The workstation is currently connected on a wired ethernet connection while we are setting it up, but eventually we want to get it onto WiFi instead.
We installed a USB Wi-Fi dongle (TP-Link Archer T2U RTL8821AU) using the aircrack-ng driver (not the aircrack toolset, just their chipset driver!) because the manufacturer doesn't have a Linux driver.
The device appears to be installed correctly. If I run ip a it returns
3: wlx40ae3041cc07: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 2312 qdisc mq state DORMANT group default qlen 1000 link/ether 66:31:fe:44:71:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 40:ae:30:41:cc:07
for that adapter.
But when I try to set up the Wi-Fi connection from the desktop session by clicking on the networking icon on the menu bar, instead of opening the popup menu, I get a message that:

System policy prevents Wi-Fi scans
An application is attempting to perform an action that requires privileges. Authentication is required to perform this action.
Password: ________
Details
Action: org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.scan
Vendor: NetworkManager

Entering my user password there just returns to the same dialog over again.
On the local desktop, entering the password works but the network manager still does not show the available networks.
First things first - how do I remove those security restrictions?
Thanks!

A lot of problems are common to Debian and Ubuntu. A similar Ubuntu problem resolved here might correspond, as it is about differing system policies for locally and remotely logged in users.

@meuh Thanks, I will look into that and feedback here. Half the newbie problem is know what to search for / where to look for the info required.

I have encountered this issue when I was connecting to a KDE session via RDP and the remote system had WiFi (it does not matter if the remote system is connected either using Ethernet or using WiFi). As per https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html you will need to write a .rules file and populate it with JavaScript code to rid of these messages or do other nerdy stuff.
You need to create a file named 50-bla-bla-bla.rules (the number is also random, just to look similar to other) in the folder /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.scan") {
      return polkit.Result.YES;
  }
});

Frankly speaking, I have little understanding of what this code actually does and how secure is this result. I guess it allows to do WiFi scans to everybody and everything.
After I added this file the irritating dialog stopped appearing, which is what I wanted to achieve. I did not even have to restart the system or re-login.
